# How does the JSession works, and how to use it in different files?

Tags: joomla-3.9, jsession, captcha

I'm using **JSession** *(in Joomla 3.9.x)* to implement sort of a *captcha field* in a form, apparently the captcha code is been saved correctly in the session but I can't find the way to retrieve it, and when I'm trying to find how to use it in the Joomla Documentation, I got to API archived pages *(what does "archived" mean?, that they are from older Joomla version?, then how / where do I search for the current version documentation?)*.

This is the file structure I'm using:

```
| - views/
| - | - form/
| - | - captcha/
```

... then in the **form** (`./views/form/tmpl/default.php`) I'm calling the captcha in this way:

```
<img src="<?php echo JURI::root(); ?>index.php?option=my_component&view=captcha&format=raw" width="120" height="40" />
```

... in the `display` method of the **captcha** view (`./views/captcha/view.raw.php`), after generating the random code I'm saving it this way *(following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18539175))*:

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->clear('myCaptchaCode');
$session->set('myCaptchaCode', $myRandomGeneratedCode);
```

Then *(here it comes!)* when I'm testing my session variables in the **form** (`./views/form/tmpl/default.php`), just imagine I refresh the form twice, and when I `echo`:

- the `$_SESSION['myCaptchaCode']`, it has the code generated in the previous page;
- and neither the `JFactory::getSession->get('myCaptchaCode')` nor the `JFactory::getSession->set('myCaptchaCode')` has the actual *(expected)* code, both are empty!

What am I doing wrong, what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

`JFactory::getSession` is a method (function).
`JFactory::getSession()->get('myCaptchaCode')` should do what you expect.

Comment: This answer has been autoflagged by the system for its length.  Can you perhaps expand on your insights by providing additional relevant insights or links to documentation?